# Kibana scripted fields

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7, scriptedfield

I have updated my ESL version to 7.17.5 and after that I am facing issue in scripted fields.

```
doc['num_likes'].value + doc['num_fb_comments'].value + doc['reply_count'].value + doc['retweet_count'].value + 1
```

Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: You probably get help a lot faster instead of saying "I am facing issues", you would tell exactly what the issue you're facing is, and what have you tried to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

In Kibana 7.17.5 scripted fields are deprecated in favor of runtime fields.
If your issue is related to the use of runtime fields: All runtime fields needs to have an emit() section in it to declare which value the field should have.